# WPF Image Dynamic Binding

Tags: wpf, image

I want to show Image in my WPF Window.
I have put this code to do so.

```
<Image  x:Name="ImageControl" Stretch="Fill" Margin="2" Source="{Binding imgSource}"/>
```

and in code behind I have put,

```
    public ImageSource imgSource
    {
        get
        {
            logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.BeginInit();
            logo.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\MyFolder\Icon.jpg");
            logo.EndInit();                
            return logo;
        }
    }
```

This code shows image fine but I also should be able to change image runtime, That is, I want to replace Icon.jpg with another Image.
MyFolder is the folder path that will contain an Image "Icon.jpg" (Name would always be same).
So whenever I try to replace Icon.jpg with anyother Image, I get an error That `Image file in Use`

Can Anyone suggest how to overcome this issue. Please let me know if I need to clear my question.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class.
- Change your property to a "get" "set"
- And don't forget to set the DataContext.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set
        {
            if (imagePath != value)
            {
                imagePath = value;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(ImagePath);
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
                imgSource = bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage logo;
    public ImageSource imgSource
    {
        get { return logo; }
        set
        {
            if (logo != value)
            {
                logo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("imgSource");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

#### UPDATE

`BitmapImage` is known to keep the file loaded when passing the path using string.
Load with a `FileStream` instead. `BitmapImage` as on demand loading capability set by default. To foce the bitmap to load the image on `EndInit` you have to change the `ChacheOption`:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyFolder\Icon.jpg"))
{
    logo = new BitmapImage();
    logo.BeginInit();
    logo.StreamSource = stream;
    logo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    logo.EndInit();
}
```